# bash scripting cat and echo

Tags: bash, scripting, echo, cat

I new in bash scripting and i bug with this:

```
    tab=( "^[A-Z]\{4,\}[0-9]\{4,\}" )

    for (( i=0; i<=$(( ${#tab[*]} - 1 )); i++ ))    
    do      
       tmp+=" grep -v \"${tab[i]}\" |"  
    done    
    # for remove the last |     
    chaine=`echo $tmp| rev | cut -c2- | rev`    
    #result anticipe "cat ${oldConfFile[0]} | grep -v "^[A-Z]\{4,\}[0-9]\{4,\}"
    cat ${oldConfFile[0]} | echo $chaine
```

My trouble is there, how use cat and echo at the same time ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: To use them at the same time, just avoid piping one into the other, that won't do anything useful.

Comment: Looks like you should use functions rather than try to execute strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to grep for each pattern, just join your patterns with pipes (`|`) and grep once. For example, if you want to filter out lines that contain `foo`, `bar` and `baz` from `file`, use the following:

```
grep -v 'foo|bar|baz' file
```

And you can build up the pattern outside of the invocation for better readability like this:

```
my_pattern='foo'
my_pattern+='|bar'
my_pattern+='|baz'

grep -v "$my_pattern" file
```